# Is setMainFrameURL really defined in webView

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, webview, webkit

I'm new to programming with cocoa. I was going to experiment with the webkit View class. According to this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/index.html

a web view should have a method called "setMainFrameURL". However, when I try to use it, I get an error message saying that the method is not defined. How is this possible? Does this method really exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setMainFrameURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setMainFrameURL:) is an Objective C method. The equivalent Swift syntax would be

```
webView.mainFrameURL = "http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is that the only thing I need to make the webView show the page? If so, it looks like it doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes, it should be. If you're still stuck, please open a new question (it is a new question after all) and don't forget to include all relevant code.